# Python - Rename file name in file attached

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, rename, file-rename

I have a Python script that sends a file attached in a mail. The mail is sent however the attachment still displays the file path of my local system. Is there any way I could rename this path that is displayed in the mail attachment.

Given below is the csv file I am trying to send as an attachment. How could I rename the path shown in the attachment to only display the file name and not include the entire path

```
attach.to_csv('/Users/user/desktop/report/file.csv')
```

I would like to display just file.csv.

I tried using `os` module but it returned an error path does not exist.

```
os.rename('/Users/user/desktop/report/file.csv','file.csv')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you are asking for, but you can get the filename without the path like so: filename_without_path = os.path.basename(filename_with_path)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dir and then attaching the file.

**Ex:**

```
import os

os.chdir('/Users/user/desktop/report')
attach.to_csv('file.csv')
```